# How to translate this C#-like code to an SQL Server stored proc

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, enumeration, pseudocode

Below is pseudo-code for SQL Server stored procedure I need to write:

```
int[] followers = (select FollowerID from StoreFollower where StoreId = @storeId)

insert into Message (senderId, recipientId)
values (@senderId, followers[0])

int rootMessageId = last_id()

foreach (int follower in followers.Skip(1))
    insert into Message (senderId, recipientId, rootMessageId)
    values (@senderId, follower, rootMessageId
```

It gets all `Store`'s follower IDs, creates a record in `Message` for the first one. Then it creates a `Message` for each subsequent follower ID, also specifying ID of the first `Message` record in the batch.

I need to convert this to SQL Server stored procedure, however I never wrote one before so I'm hesitant. Should I use a `table` variable to hold `select` result? Should I use arrays? What is the closest match to `foreach` here? How do I slice off the first element?

I would very much appreciate a sketch of such proc, just to know what to look further at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My stab at it in T-SQL. I assume that (a) `FollowerID` is `int`, (b) `@storeId` and `@senderID` ar parameters of the stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @FirstFollower int
DECLARE @FirstMessage int

--Get the first follower (i.e. smallest FollowerID, hopefully that's what you mean
--otherwise you need an appropriate ORDER BY clause here
SELECT @FirstFollower=TOP(1) FollowerId from StoreFollower 
where StoreId = @storeId

--Store message for first follower and get root message id
INSERT INTO Message (senderId, recipientId)
VALUES(@senderId, @FirstFollower)

SELECT @FirstMessage=SCOPE_IDENTITY()

--store a message per follower except the first. Same conditions apply here
--regarding the order of the followers as in the first SELECT query
INSERT INTO Message(senderId, recipientId, rootMessageId)
SELECT @senderId, FollowerID, @FirstMessage
FROM StoreFollower WHERE
FollowerID <> @FirstFollower
```

HTH